# setting up Panic Coda site with Coldfusion local development environment

Tags: macos, coldfusion-9, coda

Has anyone done this. I'm trying to get it up and running at the moment and running into trouble. The only documentation I can find is a setup through Dreamweaver and I'm using coda. I'm using a MAc and have downloaded the coldfusion environment. I'm not just trying to get a Coda site to find and access the files in the wwwroot folder in coldfusions environment.

Comment: What problems are you running into? Setting up a site (any type of site) in Coda is as simple as configuring the new site dialog. Let us know what you've tried, and specifically what isn't working, and we can get you squared away. I use Coda in conjunction with CFBuilder on a daily basis.

Comment: Thanks Dan I got it to work. One question I had about Coda. When I make a change to a file it marks it as modified and it also has a little publish arrow. So what is the difference between publish and when you right click on a file it has upload. I'm not sure I get publish. I first thought it would publish the file to the remote server but it didn't so where does published files go or what does it do?

Comment: Files to be published are files that have changed since the last time they were uploaded. When you publish a file (or publish all), they will be uploaded to your configured remote server. I've never had that fail on me :). That being said, "publish"ing something and uploading something are the same thing. They should both end up on the same spot on your remote server.

Comment: Thanks for that Dan. It's odd the upload works for me the publish doesn't. Do you have to upload the file first if it hasn't been uploaded before and then once its been upload you can use publish?

Comment: Not that I've found. What happens when you attempt to publish the file? Do you get an error, or does it end up in the wrong location on the remote server?

Comment: It says its publishing to the correct path but then it doesn't show up there. Very strange

Comment: I see whats happening not sure how to fix it. When I rollover the publish tab I see the address is incorrect. Its adding the path inside of the coldfusion server on my machine to the end of the path that I have as the "Remote Route" in the sites setup panel. Any ideas how I would stop that from happening.

Comment: Take a screen shot of your site definition and post it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Dan I'm getting a mapping error now that I have everything setup. I posted a new question here if you have time to look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478539/coldfusion-mapping-error

Answer (score 0):

I use Coda too! It's a pity the cfml syntax file is very outdated.

CFBuilder is great if you want an IDE that actually understands the cfml language, but imho looks crap.

Textmate 2 is coming soon!