# cfinclude: template not found exception + symbolic link + CF 9.0.1

Tags: coldfusion, symlink, coldfusion-9

I had following directory-structure:

```
/user1/
/user1/bla.cfm
/index.cfm
```

and created a directory called `users`:

```
/users/
/user1/
/user1/bla.cfm
/index.cfm
```

I set up a symbolic link (under linux with `ln -s`) from /user1/ to /users/user1/ and tried to `<cfinclude>` the bla.cfm which worked good. From index.cfm:

```
<CFINCLUDE template="users/user1/bla.cfm" />
```

After some testing I removed the symbolic link (/users/user1/) and moved the real directory /user1/ to /users/user1/. Suddenly the bla.cfm did not let me include and threw a template not found exception.

After setting up the symbolic link from /users/user1/ to /user1/ the `<cfinclude>` worked again. I cannot reproduce this on our development server!? Any hints how to fix this?

Btw all user-directories (user2, user3, etc.)  have a bla.cfm inside - and just 2 are having the problem described above. It seems that those users were active and the `bla.cfm` was included via the symlink. Are those symlinks and their targets cached somewhere?

**EDIT:**

I tried already clearing the template-cache in CFAdmin.

**Further testing:**
from index.cfm:

```
expandpath("/users/user1/bla.cfm") -> correct path
fileexists(expandpath("/users/user1/bla.cfm")) -> saying "YES"
```

but:

```
fileexists(expandpath("users/user1/bla.cfm")) -> saying "NO"
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your template cache in the administrator ?

Comment: Have you tried dumping expandpath("users/user1/bla.cfm") and see if it's the expected location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting coldfusion server instance fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's some issue with mappings? In the last include you're using absolute path, where in the first one you're using relative path.

Here are some links about mappings:
http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=8E676EBA-A0EF-5BB2-1461BEA3C00CC076

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/442033

[Coldfusion mapping error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478539/coldfusion-mapping-error)

Comment: there are no mapping called /users. And remember: the path I want to include is correct so that user2, user3, etc. are correctly working. Except for two...

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how you setup a 'symbolic link' - do you mean you created a mapping in CF Administrator?  If so, check the neo-runtime.xml file in your /cfusion/lib/ folder and see if has been correctly updated.

Comment: And on Windows, using a junction point (mklink /J) seems to work much better than a simple "shortcut."
I do this AND set a mapping in cfadmin.